# application throwing restricted access error when switching between tests in cypress 12

Tags: user-interface, browser, cypress, keycloak, ui-automation

I recently upgraded  cypress to 12 from 9 . we use keycloak before launching UI which is working fine in 9 . however , in 12 , it's failing switching between tests by throwing restricted-access-error in UI when tried to navigate. wondering if anyone facing the same issue? any help will be greatly appreciated. I tried explicitly clearing cookies, localstorage etc